# Same condition in C and Java, different result

Tags: java, c

In C:

```
float a = 1.3;
if (a == 1.3)
    printf("Hello c");  
else 
    printf("Bye c"); 

//output: Bye c
```

In Java:

```
float a = 1.3;
if (a == 1.3)
    System.out.println("Hello java");
else 
    System.out.println("Bye java");

//output: Hello java
```

Why is this so?

Comment: I've done several [small corrections](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/119596/revisions) in your code, there was no way your original code worked. Have you seen your code produce the output or did you just copied it from somewhere?

Answer (score 21):

You cannot exactly represent "1.3" as a binary float.

The conversion of the literal 1.3 to a float will result in a floating point number that is close to but not exactly equal to 1.3.

In the Java case you struck lucky because the JVM interprets the "1.3" as a standard java float and converts to the same almost 1.3. binary number. In the C case the standard says 1.3 should be interpreted as a "double" and converts it to a binary floating point that is a little closer to the decimal value 1.3 than the ordinary float.

The bottom line is that you should never compare floats for equality as small variations in storage, order of calculation etc. will produce slightly different results. You should always "bracket" any float comparison like so:

```
if (a > 1.299 && a < 1.301) // something close to 1.3
```

Comment: Just to be a complete nit-pick: in C, `1.3` is always a double. The syntax for (single-precision) float literals is `1.3f`.

Comment: @tdammmers -- thanks. I was not sure whether this was compiler specific or mandated by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help you wrap your brain around the answer, let me give you a simple analogy. Remember that floating point numbers are approximate. Many numbers cannot be exactly represented. Now, imagine we do the same thing with decimals, say we use six digits after the decimal place.

How do we represent 1/3? `.333333` is the best we can do. But now `3 * 1/3` will not equal 1.

How do we represent 2/3? `.666666` will at least ensure `2 * 1/3 = 2/3`. But `2/3 + 1/3` will not equal 1.

We can represent 2/3 as `.666667`. But then `2 * 1/3` won't equal `2/3`. But at least `1/3 + 2/3` will equal one.

So the point is, with approximate representations, you can't ensure exactly right answers, only close enough answers. In general, you should never compare floating point numbers for equality unless you are 100% positive you understand what you are doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that must be known with respect to C is that it is very wrong to test 2 floating point numbers for equality because of the implementation of the floating point numbers by the compiler.
'1.3' when store in a float variable ,you have not filled up all the decimal place to which the compiler stores and will likely to be filled with some digits thus giving rise to the failure for the test of equality